# Calling function in shared library (Linux) get Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, linux

I was trying to write a basic example of shared library opening and function calling for practice, but it turns out that I always get "segmentation fault" when the exectuable is actually running. Here are the source code:

---

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*API)(unsigned int);

int main(int argc,char** argv){

    void* dl;
    API api;
    unsigned int tmp;

    //...

    dl=dlopen("pluginA.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    api=(API)dlsym(dl,"API");

    cin>>tmp;
    (*api)(tmp);

    dlclose(dl);

    //...

    return 0;

    }
```

---

pluginA.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void API(unsigned int N){switch(N){
    case 0:cout<<"1\n"<<flush;break;
    case 1:cout<<"2\n"<<flush;break;
    case 2:cout<<"4\n"<<flush;break;
    case 4:cout<<"16\n"<<flush;break;}}
```

---

I compiled the two part with the following command:

```
g++ -shared -o pluginA.so -fPIC plugin.cpp
g++ main.cpp -ldl
```

---

Here is the output

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

BTW, I also tried directly call api(tmp) rather than (*api)(tmp), that also don't work. Since api is a pointer, (*api) makes more sense?

---

I'm not sure what should I do. There are many totorials about calling function in shared library online, but most of them aren't fully coded, or they actually don't work.

And also I'm not sure what should I do with "**attribute**((visibility("default")))". Should I even write it down?

---

**EDT1**
Thanks for giving me so much advice. I finally find out that actually everything is a typo in compiling command... I mistakenly typed pluginA.so to pluginA.o, and that's the reason why it don't work...

Anyway, here is my revised program, with error handling added, and more "full" system added:

main.cpp:

```
#include<dirent.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

typedef bool (*DLAPI)(unsigned int);

int main(){

    DIR* dldir=opendir("dl");
    struct dirent* dldirf;
    void* dl[255];
    DLAPI dlapi[255];
    unsigned char i,dlc=0;
    char dldirfname[255]="./dl/";
    unsigned int n;

    while((dldirf=readdir(dldir))!=NULL){
        if(dldirf->d_name[0]=='.')continue;
        strcat(dldirfname,dldirf->d_name);
        dl[dlc]=dlopen(dldirfname,RTLD_LAZY);
        if(!dl[dlc])cout<<dlerror()<<endl;else{
            dlapi[dlc]=(DLAPI)dlsym(dl[dlc],"API");
            if(!dlapi[dlc])cout<<dlerror()<<endl;else dlc++;}
        dldirfname[5]='\0';}

    if(dlc==0){
        cerr<<"ERROR:NO DL LOADED"<<endl;
        return -1;}

    while(true){
        cin>>n;
        for(i=0;i<dlc;i++)if((*dlapi[i])(n))break;
        if(i==dlc)cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;}

    for(i=0;i<dlc;i++)dlclose(dl[i]);

    return 0;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read documentation of [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and `dlsym` and you should *always* handle failure. So code

```
dl=dlopen("./pluginA.so",RTLD_LAZY);
if (!dl) { fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failure: %s\n", dlerror()); 
           exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
api=(API)dlsym(dl,"API");
if (!api)  { fprintf(stderr, "dlsym failure: %s\n", dlerror()); 
           exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

The documentation of `dlopen` is explaining why you want to pass `./pluginA.so` with a `./` prefix

At last, you should always compile with all warnings and debug info, so:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -shared -o pluginA.so -fPIC plugin.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -rdynamic main.cpp -ldl
```

<sup>(It is useful to link the main program with `-rdynamic` so that the plugin could access its symbols)</sup>

You could want to `dlclose(dl)` just before the end of `main` ... (calling or returning from a `dlsym`-ed function will crash your program if you `dlclose` too early). You might even avoid the `dlclose` (i.e. accept some resource leak). By experience you usually can `dlopen` many hundreds of thousands shared objects (see my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c))

Only once your program is debugged you could add some optimization flag like `-O` or `-O2` (and perhaps remove the debugging flag `-g`, but I don't recommend that for beginners).

You should perhaps read [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I correted your code a bit and use the error checking. Try that and get the idea what's going on:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*API)(unsigned int);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

  API api;
  unsigned int tmp;

  //...

  void* handle = dlopen("pluginA.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (!handle)
  {
    std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  dlerror();

  api = reinterpret_cast<API>(dlsym(handle, "API"));
  if (!api)
  {
    std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 2;
  }

  cin>>tmp;
  (*api)(tmp);

  dlclose(handle);

    //...

  return 0;

}
```

At last: why it is failed? Use the right path: "./pluginA.so", not "pluginA.so" or put the full path to your plugin.